# most efficient way to check neighbouring grid

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, grid

Suppose I have a large square grid represented by a two-dimensional array A of size NxN, and a point is assigned to one of the grid by on its coordinates. Each grid is surrounded by eight neighbouring grids (think of the number pad in the keyboard, no.5 is surrounded by 1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9).

Now for each of the neighbouring grids I will do something for it, but some of the elements in the array may not have eight neighbouring grids. If it is on one of the for boarders then it only has five neighbours (like no.2 is surrounded by only 1,3,4,5,6), and if it on one of the four corners then it is surrounded by only three neighbours. Given an element of the array A, how to check its neighbours in the most efficient way? I can just set up many if statements to see if its array index is larger than 0 or smaller than N-1, but how to group (nest) those if statements so that the least number of steps is required?

thanks

Comment: Do you know the size N at compile time?

Comment: "how to check its neighbours": can you be more specific ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want each element to check few conditions you can use a for loop  `i=1,j=1; i<N-1 && j<N-1; i++,j++` for the "safe" elements.

Then use a loop to iterate over each line like so `j=1;j<N-1;j++ {check array[0][j] and array[N-1][j]` and the same for i.

Now, you only need to check the corners.

In this way, no element checks more conditions then it must.

Answer (score 2):

```
pt: (i,j )
if(i>0 &&j>0&& i<n-1&&j<n-1){
//not a border element.
}
else{
  if(i+j == 0|| i+j == n-1 || i+j == 2(n-1)){
     //four corner points ie #neighbour = 3
  }
  else{
     //boundary points with #neighbour = 5
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you will have to time the different methods. This is cut straight out of a simple "Game of Life" program where it counts the number of surrounding *white* cells.

Whichever way you dice this you end up making quite a few *ifs and buts*. So I settled on this, fairly obvious, approach whereby I initially modify the start and end variables for the loops:

```
unsigned count_neighbours(const sf::Image& img, unsigned x, unsigned y)
{
    unsigned c = 0;

    auto Nx = img.getSize().x;
    auto Ny = img.getSize().y;

    unsigned xb = x ? x - 1 : x;
    unsigned yb = y ? y - 1 : y;
    unsigned xe = (x == Nx - 1) ? Nx : x + 2;
    unsigned ye = (y == Ny - 1) ? Ny : y + 2;

    for(auto xi = xb; xi < xe; ++xi)
        for(auto yi = yb; yi < ye; ++yi)
            if(xi != x || yi != y)
                if(img.getPixel(xi, yi) == sf::Color::White)
                    ++c;
    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution by @ClsForCookies is an excellent one, as the vast majority of the nodes are internal and won't require any testing.

Anyway, this is only useable if you are free to impose the visit order and if you accept to duplicate the code.

So for now I will assume that you don't known the node indexes in advance.

One option is to use an array of bits with an extra margin around the grid. The bit tells you if you are out of the grid.

Another is to use an array of codes the same size as the original grid (or add an attribute to the nodes). The code will tell you the node configuration (top-left corner, top edge...). There are nine situations. For every nine possible value, you can pre-store a list of the possible displacements to existing neighbors (3 to 8 possibilities).

Rather than storing the whole array of 9-codes, you can compute them with the formula

```
Code = (0 < i + 2 * (i >= N)) + 3 * (0 < j + 2 * (j >= N))
```

To limit storage you can also pre-store the `i` and `j` parts of the code in two 1D arrays.

Lastly, you can use the following scheme to scan around `(i, j)`:

```
if i > 0:
    i--
    if j > 0:
        j--; Process; j++
    Process
    if j < N-1:
        j++; Process; j--
    i++
if j > 0:
    j--; Process; j++
if j < N-1:
    j++; Process; j--
if i < N-1:
    i++
    if j > 0:
        j--; Process; j++
    Process
    if j < N-1:
        j++; Process; j--
    i--
```

Unfortunately, the cost is maximum (8 tests) for the internal nodes.